# Hide onscreen buttons of back, home & recent apps in Keyboard apps on Moto G5 Plus

Tags: keyboard, 7.0-nougat, motorola-moto-g5

I have Moto G5 Plus. I have enabled [One-button navigation in Moto Actions](https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/116532/~/one-button-navigation---moto-g-plus-(5th-gen.)) using which I can use the swipe actions on home button to replicate back/home/recent apps buttons. This hides the onscreen buttons of back, home & recent apps.

But when any keyboard app is open (SwiftKey, GBoard) then these buttons appear onscreen. How can I hide these buttons when keyboard app is open?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this was issue with Moto G5 Plus itself. Lenovo release an update [NPN25.137-67](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Moto-G5-Moto-G5-Plus/New-update-Discussion-NPN25-137-67/td-p/3677556) which fixes this issue and I no longer see the onscreen buttons of back, home & recent apps in Keyboard apps anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Or go to settings > display > expanded desktop and hide the navbar for your keyboard apps.

If that doesn't work, use tasker to hide the navbar when a keyboard is open.

Comment: There is no setting of 'expanded desktop'

Comment: Bummer. That must be just a lineageOS/Cyanogenmod thing.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with my phone, but that happened after I switched on the magnify option. Check if u have the accessibility icon on the right hand corner of the navigation bar. If yes just go the setting > accessibility>magnification> turn of magnify with button. The navigation bar will disappear.